# prioritization in SharePoint

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to figure out how i can add ranking column as displayed below.

I have a list with multiple columns, based on values of Count of priority qualifiers and submission date, I want to generate ranking for each task.

If Count have high value it gets' #1 rank. If count values are tied, ranking is generated based on submission date.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with (and learn) getting your formulas right using Formulas in Excel.

Most basic Functions are the same in SharePoint

A list of SharePoint Functions and examples and references to Microsoft Docs can be found here:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

If you don't succeed paste your tries here and we will help, but you have to show some effort